# How to test if n or more elements of a Collection or Sequence passes a condition without processing every element

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation

I'd like to test if a number (n) or more elements of a Sequence or Collection will return true when passed to a function. I'm not interested in how many elements would return true, just if n or more would or would not. I can get the correct result with this code:

```
 let result = collection.filter { test($0) }.count > (n-1)
```

But the `test` function is called once for each element of `collection`. Is there a better (or possibly 'lazy') way to do this?

I can do this manually but iterating over the collection something like:

```
let result:Bool = {
    var nCount = 0
    for object in collection {
        if test(object) {
            nCount = nCount + 1
            if nCount >= n {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}()
```

But the first way seems a lot more elegant.

I understand that, in a worst-case scenario, every element would have to be tested. I'm just like to avoid the unnecessary computation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case n=1 (check if at least one element of the sequence passes
the test) you can use [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/2297500-contains) with a predicate:

```
let result = sequence.contains(where: { test($0) } )
```

or just

```
let result = sequence.contains(where: test)
```

In the general case (check if the sequence contains at least a given number of matching items) you can use a lazy filter. Example:

```
func isEven(_ i : Int) -> Bool { return i % 2 == 0 }

let numbers = Array(1...10)

let atLeast4EvenNumbers = !numbers.lazy.filter(isEven).dropFirst(3).isEmpty
print(atLeast4EvenNumbers)
```

If you add a print statement to the `isEven` function then you'll see
that it is not called more often than necessary.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Is there anything so elegant if I was trying to find if instead of one or more, there was two or more?

Comment: That's amazing. I would not have thought of that. Would I be right in thinking that it's the dropFirst(3) that's causing the numbers to be evaluated? Many thanks.

Comment: @JoshParadroid: `dropFirst(3)` causes the (lazy filtered) sequence to be evaluated until 3 (even) integers are found, `isEmpty` then tries to get another (even) element. Note that this looks short and nice, but a straight-forward loop *may* have a better performance. – *Suggestion:* If you edit your question (title and body) that it covers this more general problem then I can reopen it.